# Change the visibility of a button using jquery - UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have 2 buttons (Filter and view summary) and a updatepanel.  The update panel hold the grid. When the filter button is clicked - the data is fetched from the database and the updatepanel is triggered. Now based on the contents of the data, i want to change the visibility of the view summary button.

I have tried - hfSummaryVis is the hiddenfield that i set in the update panel

```
function pageLoad() {
    alert('<%=hfSummaryVis.Value %>');
}
```

The alert message is always blank .  I have also tried document.ready.  Document.Ready is only called when the page loads for the first time.

Please help

Thanks,

```
<div id="divOrderDateSelector" class="FloatLeft PadDiv" style="padding-top: 3px;">
  <asp:Button ID="btnFilter" runat="server" Text="Filter" 
    OnClick="btnFilter_Click" CssClass="DefaultButton"/>
  <asp:Button ID="btnSummary" runat="server" Text="View Summary"
    OnClick="btnSummary_Click" CssClass="DefaultButton" 
    onclientclick="return false"/>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="divbuy" class="ClearBoth PadBottom">
  <span class="SectionHeader Block" >Buys</span>  
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upStatus" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
      <Triggers >
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFilter" EventName="Click"/>
      </Triggers>
      <ContentTemplate >
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSummaryVis" runat="server" />
        <asp:GridView ID="gvSummary" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CssClass="ContrastTable WideTable" GridLines="None" 
          onrowdatabound="gvSummary_RowDataBound">
          <EmptyDataTemplate>No Records Found</EmptyDataTemplate>
          <RowStyle CssClass="MainTableRow" />
          <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternateRow" />
          <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderRow" />
          <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lkBtnOpen" runat="server" CssClass="Expand ButtonCell PlainLink"  
                  ToolTip="Click to see details of the date's orders."
                  Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" OnClientClick="showCusipAccountDetails(" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lkBtnClose" runat="server" CssClass="Collapse ButtonCell PlainLink Hidden"
                  ToolTip="Click to close." 
                  Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" />
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Strategy Series">
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblStrategySeries" runat="server" />
              </ItemTemplate>
            ...
```

Comment: Let's see the whole javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a script manager on the page and then hook into the events of `//Do Something Here`.

Put this in the page load event:

```
if (typeof Sys !== "undefined") {
        if (typeof Sys.WebForms !== "undefined") {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(function (sender, args) {
                //Do Something Here
            });
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function (sender, args) {
                //Do Something Here
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I figure out if the button should be displayed or not.  the hiddenfield value does not update, although breakpoint the codebehind indicates that it has.

Comment: JavaScript page load. You should consider jQuery as well.

Answer (score 0):

That Hidden filed is a server control so you have to get the ClientID of that control. Try this

```
 alert('#<%= hfSummaryVis.ClientID %>').val();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that using an update panel.